# TinyMCE 6 - How to fix double quote bad html for font names with space in the name?

Tags: tinymce

Did not have this problem with previous version. Recently changed to version 6 and the html generated by the front family selector is bad html in my opinion. For all fonts with a space in the font name it puts double quotes in the html around the name and this breaks the html once saved to database. How do you fix this problem in the TinyMCE configuration? I have tried the `entity_encoding` option but that does not seem to help. For example this is a sample of the bad html:

```
<span style="font-family: "arial black", sans-serif;">ROCK</span>
```